# OSM2PGSQL cgywin package issues

Tags: osm2pgsql

I'm having an issue getting the OSM2PGSQL cgywin windows package to stay open. When I click the OSM2PGSQL.exe file after unzipping the command prompt window opens then immediately closes. I have tried opening it from command prompt to see if OSM2PGSQL would stay open but it still closes. Does anyone know how to keep it from closing.